# Valores por default MVC con entity framework y procedimientos almacenados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, stored-procedure, entity-framework-6

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado para guardar registros que tiene valores por default.

```
Guardar(@ID int, @autor varchar (20)='anonimo',@isbn int,@titulo varchar(25)='TBD',
@descripcion varchar(250)='N/A')




public virtual int Guardar(ObjectParameter ID, string autor,int isbn ,string titulo,string descripcion )
        {
            var autorParameter = autor != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Autor", autor) :
                new ObjectParameter("Autor", typeof(string));

            var isbnParameter = isbn != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Isbn", isbn) :
                new ObjectParameter("Isbn", typeof(int));

        var tituloParameter = titulo != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Titulo", titulo) :
                new ObjectParameter("Titulo", typeof(string));

        var descripcion Parameter = descripcion  != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Descripcion ", descripcion ) :
                new ObjectParameter("Descripcion ", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("Guardar", ID, autorParameter, isbnParameter, tituloParameter, descripcionParameter);
        }
```

Al compilarlo funciona poniendo todos los datos en los textbox pero si no pongo nada en algun textbox que tiene valor por defualt me marca error en el `db.SaveChanges();`

```
Mensaje de error "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."
```

**¿Hay alguna forma en que la aplicacion acepte los valores por default del store procedure?**

Estoy usando visual 2017 y sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces esto:

```
var autorParameter = autor != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Autor", autor) :
                new ObjectParameter("Autor", typeof(string));
```

Estás creando el parámetro pero queda en un estado sin inicializar, eso te puede traer problemas con el EF. Prueba pasando `DBNull.Value` para los valores nulos.

```
 if (autor != null)
    {
        autorParameter = new ObjectParameter("Autor", autor);
    }
    else
    {
        autorParameter = new ObjectParameter("Autor", typeof(string))
        autorParameter .Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Sigue saliendo el error en el db.SaveChanges(); compañero

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta para incluir el mensaje de error.